# multiple for with less.curious lib

Tags: for-loop, less

when I use [less.curious](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) for multiple loop, that don't work correctly.

example:

y.less:

```
@import "for";
@list-y: 'I', 'You', 'others';
.for(@list-y); .-each(@type) {
  @y-class: ~'.y-@{type}';
  @{y-class} {
    y: @type;
  }
}
```

x.less:

```
@import "for";
@list-x: 'less', 'cirious', 'somebody', 'somebody-else';
.for(@list-x); .-each(@type) {
  @x-class: ~'.x-@{type}';
  @{x-class} {
    x: @type;
  }
}
```

both.less:

```
@import "x";
@import "y";
```

`lessc x.less` and `lessc y.less` working correctly. `lessc both.less` must be concatenation of `lessc x.less` and `lessc y.less`, but `lessc both.less`'s output is Cartesian product.

```
$ lessc both.less
.x-less {
  x: 'less';
}
.y-less {
  y: 'less';
}
.x-cirious {
  x: 'cirious';
}
.y-cirious {
  y: 'cirious';
}
...
.x-I {
  x: 'I';
}
.y-I {
  y: 'I';
}
...
```

And the problem: How to fix that?

Useful [link](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/for-each.md)

Note:

```
$ lessc -v
lessc 1.7.5 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

Comment: use `@import (once) "for";`

Comment: no change happen. even when I move both `x.less` and `y.less` file in one file with one `import` has same result as `both.less`.

Comment: you are right, the "for" is still imported twice that way, you could create a index.less file that `@import "for"; @import "x"; @import "y";` and compile that. Notice that when you have two mixins with the same name both are compied.

Comment: Btw., just in case, you don't really need thing like `@y-class: ~'.y-@{type}';` since you already perform the interpolation with the selector interpolation the line below: `.y-@{type} {y: @type;}`.

Answer (score 1):

I found some bad answer. but it works. warp `for` with `&{ ... }`

for example `y.less`:

```
@import "for";
@list-y: 'I', 'You', 'others';
&{
.for(@list-y); .-each(@type) {
  @y-class: ~'.y-@{type}';
  @{y-class} {
    y: @type;
  }
}
}
```

and same change in `x.less`.

Comment: will it seems `&{}` creates a 'parent' scope of the main scope. Calling the `.for` mixin in the main, makes the `-each` mixin available in this parent scope, but not inn the main scope itself.

Comment: Yep, it's already in the examps but I guess I need some [reordering there](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/pull/1).